# Ms Visual Studio 2012, "unresolved external symbol"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, lnk2019, unresolved-external

I am trying to compile a C++ application through Microsoft Visual Studio 2012. I have linked the Boost, Jni, Acml libraries to the application.

When I click on rebuild, the compilation does not finish.
This is the first error I get:

> Error 28  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _sgesdd referenced
>   in function "void __cdecl testLapackDGESDD_EASY(void)"
>   (?testLapackDGESDD_EASY@@YAXXZ)   C:\Users\DavideChicco\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2012\Projects\Solution\mainConsole.obj

Do you have any idea of what this is related to?

Thanks

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/1782465); you're most likely not linking LAPACK.

Comment: I miss "too localised"

Answer (score 1):

Your compilation seems to have finished, but the error happens during linking: the definition of the function `_sgesdd` called in `testLapackDGESDD_EASY` is not found.  So
  - either this function is defined in an external `dll`, and you need to add the `lib` in your solution,
  - or this function is supposed to be defined in your project, and you need to implement its definition.

Comment: That's his own function, it is "sgesdd" that the linker can't find.

Answer (score 1):

aha, The compiler cant't find the function "_sgesdd", I recommend you that add the lib which is supplied by the author of DLL.